# BufferedReader.read returns -1 before reading the whole message

Tags: java, sockets, boost-asio

My C++ server sends my Java client a message using the following code:

```
tcp::socket* server_socket;
vector<uchar> buff; //its size is 45682
...
//Sending vector's size
stringstream ss;
ss << buff.size();
string str_size = zeroWraper(ss.str(), 10); //Adding leading zeros to the size
boost::asio::write(*server_socket, boost::asio::buffer(str_size), ignored_error);

//Sending the vector
size_t check_size = boost::asio::write(*server_socket, boost::asio::buffer(buff, buff.size()), ignored_error);
```

check_size value is 45682.

My Java client Receives the message using the following code:

```
Socket tcpSocket = new Socket("localhost", 5000);
BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(tcpSocket.getInputStream()));
...
String temp = "";
boolean error = false;
for(int i=0; i<10 && !error; i++)
{
    temp += (char)inFromServer.read();
    if(temp.equals("e")) //When there is an error on the server side, it sends 'e'
        error = true;
} //No error here and temp is 0000045682 as expected.

int mat_size = Integer.parseInt(temp);
byte mat_arr[] = new byte[mat_size];
while(!inFromServer.ready()){
    //Go to sleep
}
for(int i=0; i < mat_size && !error; i++)
{
    mat_arr[i] = (byte)inFromServer.read();
    if((int)mat_arr[i] == -1)
        error = true;
}
```

I executed this code couple of times, and every time read returns -1 when i is equal to 21212.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Edit: when ignoring the end of stream, read() reads 44278 bytes

```
for(int i=0; i < mat_size && !error; i++)
    mat_arr[i] = (byte)inFromServer.read();
```

Comment: `-1` indicated that end of the stream has been reached. Java doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29

Comment: I'm pretty sure the default buffer size is 8192 characters, maybe try setting a buffer size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that you interpret the result of `read()` as a byte instead of an `int`. Bytes (and integers) in Java are signed, so the integer 255 (0xFF) when cast to byte is -1. While you should test for the integer 0xFFFFFFFF (-1) when testing for end of stream.

Change your code to:

```
for (int i=0; i < mat_size && !error; i++) {
    int value = inFromServer.read();
    if (value == -1) {
        error = true; // Actually: end of stream, not error...
    } else {
        mat_arr[i] = (byte) value;
    }
}
```

The second problem is that you try to read bytes from a [`Reader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html). A reader is for reading characters, not bytes (but because of the `-1`, the return type is `int` not `char`). And as you construct one with `new InputStreamReader(InputStream)`, it uses the default platform character set.

If the platform default is UTF-8 (like it is on Linux), than for each character `read()` from the reader, one or more bytes will be read from the stream which could account for the discrepancy in the actual bytes read versus the expected number of bytes read.

So: drop the use of a `BufferedReader` and read the bytes directly from an [`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html), or if the data is actually character data, then make sure you 1) use `char` and `char[]` and 2) specify the expected encoding when constructing the `Reader`.

It is important to realize that a Java `char` is not the same as a C or C++ `char`.

Comment: Please look at the edit. When ignoring the '-1', BufferedReader won't read the whole message.

Comment: @EliranKoren That is because you read only the number of bytes that were actually sent. One more read will either block, or return -1 (if the stream has been closed). However still my answer and the answer by Radiodef still stands as an explanation why you incorrectly attribute the (byte) -1 to be an end of stream, instead of the (int) -1.

Comment: @EliranKoren I updated my answer, there is a second problem I didn't initially see.

Comment: Well, that explains why using BufferedInputStream worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This little casting exchange is a problem:

```
mat_arr[i] = (byte)inFromServer.read();
if((int)mat_arr[i] == -1)
```

The reason `read` normally returns int is precisely so -1 can be returned to indicate end of stream. -1 is a value outside the lower 8-bits of an int. Casting to a byte defeats this and instead the expression `(int)mat_arr[i] == -1` will evaluate true if `mat_arr[i]` was also an 8-bit -1 (or 255 since you are writing uchar).

If you need to check the -1 for some reason, you need to keep it as int while you do that, e.g.:

```
int read = inReadFromServer.read();
if(read == -1)
    error = true;

mat_arr[i] = (byte)read;
```

Comment: Please look at the edit. When ignoring the '-1', BufferedReader won't read the whole message.

Comment: Your comment in the code indicates the size of the vector is written and read correctly so I don't really see a reason for that to be the case. Is an exception being thrown (and if not, can you be sure of that)?

Comment: No exception was thrown. I used BufferedInputStream instead of BufferedReader and it worked(when ignoring '-1'). Weird.

Comment: If using an InputStream instead of a Reader works my guess is it is a decoding error. A Java char is UTF-16 and InputStreamReader may very well be interpreting the bytes coming in and consolidating certain ones in to pairs. This type of error is fairly common.